# nltk k-means clustering or k-means with pure python

Tags: python, nltk

Though I have seen quite a number of questions relating to this but i don't really get the answer may be because am a novice in using nltk clustering.
I really need a basic explanation for a novice to clustering especially on vector representation for NLTK K-mean clustering and how to use it. I have a list of words like [cat, dog, kitten, puppy etc] and two other lists of words like [carnivore, herbivore, pet, etc] and [mammal, domestic etc]. I want to be able to cluster the last two lists of words based on the first using the first as the means or centroid. I have tried, I received AssertionError like this:

```
clusterer = cluster.KMeansClusterer(2, euclidean_distance, initial_means=means)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\cluster\kmeans.py", line 64, in __init__
    assert not initial_means or len(initial_means) == num_means

AND
    print clusterer.cluster(vectors, True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\cluster\util.py", line 55, in cluster
    self.cluster_vectorspace(vectors, trace)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\cluster\kmeans.py", line 82, in cluster_vectorspace
    self._cluster_vectorspace(vectors, trace)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\cluster\kmeans.py", line 113, in _cluster_vectorspace
    index = self.classify_vectorspace(vector)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\cluster\kmeans.py", line 137, in classify_vectorspace
    dist = self._distance(vector, mean)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\cluster\util.py", line 118, in euclidean_distance
    diff = u - v
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'numpy.ndarray'
```

I think there is something I means in the vector representation. A basic example of the vector representation and example code will be highly appreciated. Any solution using nltk or pure python will be appreciated. Thanks in advance for your kind response

Comment: would you mind pointing to some of those questions/answers relating to this please? :)

Comment: If you are comparing strings shouldn't you be using hamming or levenstein distance instead of euclidean?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, something like this should work. The hard part of kmeans is to find the cluster centers, if your already found the centers or know what centers you want, you can: for every point find a distance to each cluster center and assign the point to the closest cluster center.

(As a side note [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html) is a great package for clustering and machine learning in general.)

In your example it should look like this:

[Levenstein](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance)

```
# levenstein function is not my implementation; I copied it from the 
# link above 
def levenshtein(s1, s2):
    if len(s1) < len(s2):
        return levenshtein(s2, s1)

    # len(s1) >= len(s2)
    if len(s2) == 0:
        return len(s1)

    previous_row = xrange(len(s2) + 1)
    for i, c1 in enumerate(s1):
        current_row = [i + 1]
        for j, c2 in enumerate(s2):
            insertions = previous_row[j + 1] + 1 # j+1 instead of j since previous_row and current_row are one character longer
            deletions = current_row[j] + 1       # than s2
            substitutions = previous_row[j] + (c1 != c2)
            current_row.append(min(insertions, deletions, substitutions))
        previous_row = current_row

    return previous_row[-1]

def get_closest_lev(cluster_center_words, my_word):
    closest_center = None
    smallest_distance = float('inf')
    for word in cluster_center_words:
        ld = levenshtein(word, my_word)
        if ld < smallest_distance:
            smallest_distance = ld
            closest_center = word
    return closest_center

def get_clusters(cluster_center_words, other_words):
    cluster_dict = {}
    for word in cluster_center_words:
        cluster_dict[word] = []
    for my_word in other_words:
        closest_center = get_closest_lev(cluster_center_words, my_word)
        cluster_dict[closest_center].append(my_word)
    return cluster_dict
```

Example:

```
cluster_center_words = ['dog', 'cat']
other_words = ['dogg', 'kat', 'frog', 'car']
```

Result:

```
>>> get_clusters(cluster_center_words, other_words)
{'dog': ['dogg', 'frog'], 'cat': ['kat', 'car']}
```

Comment: @akavall: this is great but how can we make this classify the words semantically rather than based on the character based distance? like categorizing everything that is a fish as a fish and everything that is a bird as a bird?